# How to use delegates to abstract the way of calling base members in subclasses?

Tags: c++, inheritance, delegates

I'm working with the following class design and would like to get rid of the same for-loop in each of the forwarding method calls by using some sort of delegate/member pointer. Is this somehow possible?

```
class Type
{
  void func_v();
  // more methods ...

  bool func_b();
  // ...

  unsigned func_u();
  // ...  
}

class MultiType : public Type
{
  void func_v() override
  {
    for(Type* type : _typeVec)
      type->func_v();
  }

  bool func_b() override
  {
    bool result = true;
    for(Type* type : _typeVec)
      result = result && type->func_b();
    return result;
  }

  unsigned func_u() override
  {
    int count = 0;
    for(Type* type : _typeVec)
      count += type->func_u();
    return count;
  }

  protected:
    std::vector<Type*> _typeVec;
}
```

What I'm looking for is something similar to this:

```
class MultiType : public Type
{
  void applyMember(MemberType member)
  {
    for(Type* type : _typeVec)
      // how to deal with varying parameters and parameter types here?
      type->member(...)

    // how to deal with varying return values and processing strategies to combine those?
  }

  void func_v() override
  {
    applyMember(&Type::func_v);
  }

  bool func_b() override
  {
    applyMember(&Type::func_b);
  }

  unsigned func_u() override
  {
    applyMember(&Type::func_u);
  }

  protected:
    std::vector<Type*> _typeVec;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your example functions perform different actions I would recommend you to look into [accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) and [for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) algorithms.

You could replace your raw loops with something like this:

```
 bool func_b() override
 {
     return std::accumulate(_typeVec.begin(), _typeVec.end(), true, [](const bool &result, const Type *t) {
         return result && type->func_b();
     });
 }

 void func_v() override
 {
      std::for_each(_typeVec.begin(), _typeVec.end(), [](Type *type){type->func_v()});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "*What I'm looking for...*" part in your question doesn't work. For example, `func_b` doesn't return any value. Even if you could do something like that using a combination of template functions and lambdas, you'd have the same independent parts in all functions (local variable declaration, reduction mechanism, `return` statement). The *only* thing you could abstract away is the `for` loop, but that's just a single line you'll be replacing with a different line.

There's no point doing that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you would want to call the same method, and possibly use the same parameters, on each object.

For example, in your production code, func_v would take parameters. This may be different from func_b that may not take parameters.

Let us assume that func_v takes in a int.

In this case, would this be true?

```
MultiType::func_v(int value) {
    for (Type* type : _typeVec)
        type->func_v(value); //note: same value being passed to all
}
```

You may want to use functors here. However, I don't think that will work well with multiple return values.

Functors can be used to aggregate values. Is that what you want to do?

Forgetting abstracting the loop out, how will you return multiple values from func_v above?

So if returning multiple values is not a problem, functors can be what you want to do.

It may be too much work for too little though. You will have to find out if it is worth it in your production code.